# It's possible to use the function max() in a variable with character type?

Tags: genexus

I need to get the max number of an character record in my database.

Yes, this column is defined Character but contains a sequence of numbers, we can't change in database the type of this record to numeric.

So, i try to get the max number of this character in this way:

```
&embacod = str(max(EmbaCod.ToNumeric(), + 1))
```

But i receive:

> error spc0026: Formula 'max( val( EmbaCod ) ) ' cannot be evaluated in
>   this program.

Also tried:

```
&EmbaCods = DpEmbalagens()
for &P0126 in &EmbaCods order (&P0126.EmbaCod.ToNumeric())
    &embacod = &P0126.EmbaCod
    exit
endfor
```

There's a workaround to get this max character number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max aggregate/select function is defined only for attributes and not expressions.

The workaround is to define a Numeric formula in the same transaction where EmbaCod is defined:

`EmbaCodFor` of type *Numeric(...)* with formula `EmbaCod.ToNumeric()`

and then in your code use

```
&embacod = str(max(EmbaCodFor))
```

Comment: I created in my transation the EmbaCodFor type Numeric 11, with formula &embacod = str(max(EmbaCodFor)) but 
I receive: "Error to convert type varchar to numeric

Comment: the formula should be `EmbaCod.ToNumeric()`

Comment: I have one problem, in this EmbaCod i have records with ".", i try to &EmbaCodFor = max(EmbaCodFor) and in the formula i create this procedure: RetiraPontosEmbaCod(EmbaCod) and in the procedure i remove the . and pass to numeric: &EmbaCod.replace(".", "")
&EmbaCodNum = &EmbaCod.ToNumeric() but i'm receiving Formula 'max( EmbaCodFor ) ' cannot be evaluated in this program

Comment: You should not call a procedure within a max formula. If you just need to strip dots you can change your `EmbaCodFor` formula to `EmbaCod.replace(".","").ToNumeric()`

Comment: Ok i also have " " space characters, i tried: EmbaCod.replace(".","").replace(" ","").tonumeric() in the formula, but i'm still receiving: Error in conversion data type varchar to numeric

Comment: you probably have some record with other characters

Comment: I search record by record and i only have Numbers, "." and one blank...

Comment: i found in the documentation of genexus this: (*) Converting alphanumerics to numerics is not supported when the method is evaluated in the DBMS (see Server Side Functions/Methods or SAC 42709).

Comment: and in the tracking stack i found: [GxADODataException: Type:GeneXus.Data.GxADODataException.DBMS

Comment: that SAC states that if you have any symbol other than numbers then it will fail, which is what's happening to you.